# Move referenced iTunes Audio files to another drive/folder

Tags: itunes, audio, external-disk, mp3

well, my iTunes library is on my main HD whereas audio files are on an external drive. I have to change the drive for these files and / or folder name, how do I point iTunes library to that drive/folder?

Comment: I had [a similar issue](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131099/how-can-i-run-a-partially-referenced-itunes-library). The answer for me was [TuneSpan](http://tunespan.com)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way I think is to use the built in iTunes setting for choosing a library location.

[image]

- First make a copy of your library on your external drive
- Then change the settings in iTunes to reflect the new location
- Profit

Apple also has support documents available to describe the required steps in more detail, both for [Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1449) and [Windows](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1364).

Comment: It's not possible. As i've written before, my iTunes library is on internal HD though the audio files are on the external.

Comment: The iTunes library files are going to always be on your internal HD, even when media is moved off.

Answer (score 0):

I got this by googling..

> When I clicked on the missing title (which is indicated by a "!") iTunes asked my to locate the file; after finding it using Spotlight it was added. Then iTunes asked me if I want to locate similar files which I confirmed an there - all missing files where found.
>   However, I had to UNCHECK "keep iTunes Media folder organized" BEFORE doing this. After I rechecked it again.

It's ok for me at the moment!